# What happened to Robb's crown?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

What happened to Robb Stark's crown after

> He was assassinated at the Red Wedding?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We see the crown in AFFC when Jaime goes to break the siege on Riverrun, and the Frey heir has a whore with him who is wearing the crown, saying she is the "queen o' whores". (*A Feast for Crows* page 570)

> Ser Ryman came stomping up the gallows steps in company with a straw-haired slattern as drunk as he was. Her gown was laced up the front, but someone had undone the laces to the navel, so her breasts were spilling out. They were large and heavy, with big brown nipples. On her head a circlet of hammered bronze sat askew, graven with runes and ringed with small black swords.

Jaime then sends Ryman Frey away, and says that he may not take the crown. Later on, in Brienne's chapter page 637, we see Lady Stoneheart:

> Behind [the table] sat a woman all in grey, cloaked and hooded. In her hands was a crown, a bronze circlet ringed by iron swords. She was studying it, her fingers stroking the blades as if to test their sharpness. Her eyes glimmered under her hood.

We also later learn that Ryman Frey was ambushed on his way home from Riverrun and killed.

> ...Edwyn blurted out, "My father's blood is on your hands, ser."
>
> That took Jaime a bit aback. "How so?"
>
> "You were the one who sent him home, were you not?"
>
> *Someone had to.* "Has some ill befallen Ser Ryman?"
>
> "Hanged with all his party," said Walder Rivers. "The outlaws caught them two leagues south of fairmarket."
>
> "Dondarrion?"
>
> "Him, or Thoros, or this woman Stoneheart."

Presumably, Ser Ryman took the crown with him when he left Riverrun (despite Jaime's command not to) and was ambushed and hanged by Stoneheart. Some small measure of justice for her, including recovering Robb's crown.

The summary of who is in possession of the crown is [here](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Crown#Crown_of_Robb_Stark).

Comment: Lady Stoneheart is later seen by Brienne to be twirling a crown on a table.

Comment: @Mooz Yes... or like I said in my answer, and it says in the book: `In her hands was a crown, a bronze circlet ringed by iron swords. She was studying it, her fingers stroking the blades as if to test their sharpness.`

Comment: I maaaaay have skimmed your answer and missed that part :)

Comment: @Mooz So I gathered. :P

Answer (score 8):

This is not a full answer, since I don't know how canon it is, but [Wikia](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Catelyn_Tully) has a picture of Lady Stoneheart

> (Catelyn resurrected)

with Robb's crown:
[image]

We can assume that she got hold of the crown after the massacre of the Red Wedding.

**ETA**
There's canon proof from the books that Lady Stoneheart does in-fact have possession of the crown:
[*A Feast of Crows* spoiler]

> A trestle table had been set up across the cave, in a cleft in the rock. Behind it sat a woman all in grey, cloaked and hooded. **In her hands was a crown, a bronze circlet ringed by iron swords.** She was studying it, her fingers stroking the blades as if to test their sharpness. Her eyes glimmered under her hood.
> <sup>*-A Song of Ice and Fire: A Feast for Crows, Chapter Thirty-Seven (Brienne).* [emphasis added]</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any specific mention in the books or show. But Robb was presumably wearing the crown at the Red Wedding, and given that

> none of the Starks in the room with Robb made it out alive

it would have been kept by one of his enemies. The most likely candidate is

> Roose Bolton, since he dealt the final blow to Robb.

Comment: Ryman Frey had the crown, it was shown in AFFC. More details in my answer.

Comment: Good answer, I'd forgotten about that part.